# 'AND' and 'OR' in SQL queries

Tags: mysql

I was hoping someone could give me a hand on how I write this correctly.

```
$details_quey = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE ONLINE = 'true' OR FORCE_AWAY = 'true' OR AWAY = 'true' AND FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false' AND TOKEN = '$con_token' ", $CON )
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what it should do first.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what "correctly" means?  What happens with this query?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @All - because of bool expressions this result will yield some unexpected values because of AND's and OR's.  Phil needs some ( ) parenthesis.

Comment: @All - people downvoting this have probably never dealt with boolean logic.  A simple look at what is being asked will right away state the problem, no one even has to ask a question.  So stop downvoting questions that you know make sense.

Comment: I'm not downvoting it, but it's not a useful question until Phil can explain the intended result.  There is no way to explicitly identify the correct nesting of ANDs and ORs with the lack of information provided.

Comment: @Joe - Most anyone with an answer could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE (ONLINE = 'true' OR FORCE_AWAY = 'true' OR AWAY = 'true') AND FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false' AND TOKEN = '$con_token' ",
```

Just use some braces to keep the and or logic seperate.  Check if the person is online or force away or away AND that the forceoffline is false and token value = con token.

Comment: simply explained, bobs you uncle! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` 
WHERE 
(ONLINE = 'true' OR FORCE_AWAY = 'true' OR AWAY = 'true')
AND FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false' AND TOKEN = '$con_token'
```

Guessing a bit, but I think that is what you want.

Assuming you want anything matching any one of the ORs and all of the ANDs

Answer (score 1):

`AND` has precedence over `OR` in a SQL Query. Therefore, your query valuates as such right now:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE
    ONLINE = 'true' OR
    FORCE_AWAY = 'true' OR
    ( AWAY = 'true' AND 
    FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false' AND
    TOKEN = '$con_token' );
```

Simply use `( )` to group conditions which should be evaluated together:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE
    (ONLINE = 'true' OR
    FORCE_AWAY = 'true') OR
    (AWAY = 'true' AND 
    FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false') AND
    TOKEN = '$con_token' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for, but brackets sure will help for the `OR`'s:

```
$details_quey = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE (ONLINE = 'true' OR FORCE_AWAY = 'true' OR AWAY = 'true') AND FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false' AND TOKEN = '$con_token' ", $CON )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but assume you want:

(online = true OR force_away=true OR away=true)
AND
force_offline=false AND token=$con_token

Your ORs need to be grouped together in parenthesis or the ANDs won't make much sense.

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE (ONLINE = 'true' OR FORCE_AWAY = 'true' OR AWAY = 'true' AND FORCE_OFFLINE = 'false') AND TOKEN = '$con_token
```